# MySQL - Select where both field1 and field2 are greater than 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a select query which I select from a table where field1 and field2 are both greater than 0.

NB field1 & field2 are both INT / NOT NULL.

i've tried doing something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE field1 > "0" AND field2 > "0"

SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE field1 <> "0" AND field2 <> "0"

SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE field1 != "0" AND field2 != "0"
```

However, when i was just matching whether either or was = 0, this query does work -

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE field1 = "0"
```

I need to check these to produce a list of applicants who've received a grading on their applications, so both field1 and field2 must have been satisfied, so it is assumed that with numerical grading that matching for greater than 0 would work, but for some reason it doesn't?

Comment: field1 is an integer or is  a string ?

Comment: If the fields are of type INT you should be comparing them to zero, not a string literal.

Comment: comparing direct to zero doesn't work, comparing to a string literal does for some reason on the singular query of comparing to zero. Both fields are integers.

Comment: @scaisEdge Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @GiantKiwi Define 'doesn't work'. *This* doesn't work: otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Are  you try it..... field1 <> 0 AND field2 <>0 @GiantKiwi

Comment: @EJP .. i don't understand you comment  ..please explain ..

Comment: What part of "define 'doesn't work'" don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a neater code, you can use `LEAST()` which takes the smaller argument placed inside the parantheses .

I believe your problem is that you are comparing ranges on strings instead of numbers( you mentioned those are numeric fields) :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE LEAST(field1,field2) > 0
```

If that doesn't solve your problem - edit your question and define "doesn't work" , nothing is being selected? Throws an error? ..

Comment: Well, this seems to have worked as intended, so i'll go with it - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE field1 <> 0 AND field2 <> 0
```